# Is the any better way to get useparams in my context provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm learning context and having a route : /show/:id

I have a context and want to access the params ID of /show/:id inside it.
To acheive what I want I just set a state to an empty string in my context and I used it in /show/:id to set the id with useParams.

It works as I want but I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve what I want and get a cleaner code.

my app.js looks like this :

```js
  <Route exact path="/discover" component={Discover} />
   <ShowDetailsProvider>
      // here I want :id in "showDetailsProvider"
     <Route exact path="/show/:id" component={ShowDetails} />
   </ShowDetailsProvider>
 <Route exact path="/show/episode/:id" component={ShowEpisode} />
```

my ShowDetailsContext is :

```js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const ShowDetailsContext = createContext();

const ShowDetailsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [idSerie, setIdSerie] = useState("");

  console.log(idSerie);

  return <ShowDetailsContext.Provider value={{ setIdSerie }}>{children}</ShowDetailsContext.Provider>;
};

export { ShowDetailsProvider, ShowDetailsContext };
```

And my ShowDetails.js

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { ShowDetailsContext } from "../context/ShowDetailsContext";

const ShowDetails = () => {
  const showDetailsContext = useContext(ShowDetailsContext);
  const { id } = useParams();
  showDetailsContext.setIdSerie(id);

  return (
    <>
      <p>show detail page</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default ShowDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty clean, simple, and readable. The only comment I have is why are you capturing the id on context? Assuming you have other uses for it, otherwise placing it into context is sort of a loop.

Comment: Because I will have many inner components inside <ShowDetails /> and few needs the /:id to make some api calls. So instead of using "let {id} = useparams()" over and over I prefer take the advantage of my context to do it. Of course I will use my context to do others things and avoid pass props from component "A" to components "D" for exemple (if you know what I mean)